# Let user change a session scope attribute with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I'm having a problem understanding how Spring handles session scope attributes.

In my view I am setting a session attribute (if one doesn't already exist)

```
<c:set scope="session" value="${not empty date ? date: thisWeek}" var="date"/>
```

Now if I would let a user click some link with the attribute appended, I could retrieve the parameter from the path in my controller and put it in the session with

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("date", date);
```

But I think I'm doing it wrong way, I'd like to know how to do it properly in Spring.

Comment: Why do you think you are doing wrong?

Comment: If you are usiong Spring you can use Spring MVC. In  Spring MVC you can add your session attributes as "Model.addattribute("date", new Date()). below is an example of it.                                                          @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }